# rviz crash on macOS Sierra

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

After lots of tweaks, I've finally made it to setup ROS Kinetic on my MacBook Air, with mac OS Sierra.
Everything works fine except `rviz`. It crashes on startup. I tried with this command:

```
rosrun rviz rviz -l
```

And the output is:

```
[ INFO] [1482424510.671672000]: rviz version 1.12.4
[ INFO] [1482424510.671803000]: compiled against Qt version 5.7.0
[ INFO] [1482424510.671830000]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
[ INFO] [1482424511.705687000]: Creating resource group General
[ INFO] [1482424511.705788000]: Creating resource group Internal
[ INFO] [1482424511.705827000]: Creating resource group Autodetect
[ INFO] [1482424511.705940000]: SceneManagerFactory for type 'DefaultSceneManager' registered.
[ INFO] [1482424511.706240000]: Registering ResourceManager for type Material
[ INFO] [1482424511.706289000]: Registering ResourceManager for type Mesh
[ INFO] [1482424511.706321000]: Registering ResourceManager for type Skeleton
[ INFO] [1482424511.706382000]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'ParticleSystem' registered.
[ INFO] [1482424511.706445000]: OverlayElementFactory for type Panel registered.
[ INFO] [1482424511.706476000]: OverlayElementFactory for type BorderPanel registered.
[ INFO] [1482424511.706510000]: OverlayElementFactory for type TextArea registered.
[ INFO] [1482424511.706549000]: Registering ResourceManager for type Font
[ INFO] [1482424511.706587000]: ArchiveFactory for archive type FileSystem registered.
[ INFO] [1482424511.706612000]: ArchiveFactory for archive type Zip registered.
[ INFO] [1482424511.706637000]: DDS codec registering
[ INFO] [1482424511.706691000]: FreeImage version: 3.17.0
[ INFO] [1482424511.706724000]: This program uses FreeImage, a free, open source image library supporting all common bitmap formats. See http://freeimage.sourceforge.net for details
[ INFO] [1482424511.706908000]: Supported formats: bmp,ico,jpg,jif,jpeg,jpe,jng,koa,iff,lbm,mng,pbm,pbm,pcd,pcx,pgm,pgm,png,ppm,ppm,ras,tga,targa,tif,tiff,wap,wbmp,wbm,psd,cut,xbm,xpm,gif,hdr,g3,sgi,rgb,rgba,bw,exr,j2k,j2c,jp2,pfm,pct,pict,pic,3fr,arw,bay,bmq,cap,cine,cr2,crw,cs1,dc2,dcr,drf,dsc,dng,erf,fff,ia,iiq,k25,kc2,kdc,mdc,mef,mos,mrw,nef,nrw,orf,pef,ptx,pxn,qtk,raf,raw,rdc,rw2,rwl,rwz,sr2,srf,srw,sti,x3f,webp,jxr,wdp,hdp
[ INFO] [1482424511.706943000]: Registering ResourceManager for type HighLevelGpuProgram
[ INFO] [1482424511.707169000]: Registering ResourceManager for type Compositor
[ INFO] [1482424511.707464000]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'Entity' registered.
[ INFO] [1482424511.707513000]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'Light' registered.
[ INFO] [1482424511.707546000]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardSet' registered.
[ INFO] [1482424511.707575000]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'ManualObject' registered.
[ INFO] [1482424511.707607000]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardChain' registered.
[ INFO] [1482424511.707636000]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'RibbonTrail' registered.
[ INFO] [1482424511.707859000]: *-*-* OGRE Initialising
[ INFO] [1482424511.707901000]: *-*-* Version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1482424511.707944000]: Loading library /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4/lib/libRenderSystem_GL
[ INFO] [1482424511.715310000]: Installing plugin: GL RenderSystem
[ INFO] [1482424511.715470000]: OpenGL Rendering Subsystem created.
[ INFO] [1482424511.715731000]: Plugin successfully installed
[ INFO] [1482424511.715784000]: Loading library /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4/lib/libPlugin_OctreeSceneManager
[ INFO] [1482424511.722139000]: Installing plugin: Octree & Terrain Scene Manager
[ INFO] [1482424511.722224000]: Plugin successfully installed
[ INFO] [1482424511.722266000]: Loading library /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4/lib/libPlugin_ParticleFX
[ INFO] [1482424511.728896000]: Installing plugin: ParticleFX
[ INFO] [1482424511.728966000]: Particle Emitter Type 'Point' registered
[ INFO] [1482424511.729014000]: Particle Emitter Type 'Box' registered
[ INFO] [1482424511.729069000]: Particle Emitter Type 'Ellipsoid' registered
[ INFO] [1482424511.729102000]: Particle Emitter Type 'Cylinder' registered
[ INFO] [1482424511.729130000]: Particle Emitter Type 'Ring' registered
[ INFO] [1482424511.729159000]: Particle Emitter Type 'HollowEllipsoid' registered
[ INFO] [1482424511.729187000]: Particle Affector Type 'LinearForce' registered
[ INFO] [1482424511.729210000]: Particle Affector Type 'ColourFader' registered
[ INFO] [1482424511.729232000]: Particle Affector Type 'ColourFader2' registered
[ INFO] [1482424511.729269000]: Particle Affector Type 'ColourImage' registered
[ INFO] [1482424511.729292000]: Particle Affector Type 'ColourInterpolator' registered
[ INFO] [1482424511.729352000]: Particle Affector Type 'Scaler' registered
[ INFO] [1482424511.729391000]: Particle Affector Type 'Rotator' registered
[ INFO] [1482424511.729488000]: Particle Affector Type 'DirectionRandomiser' registered
[ INFO] [1482424511.729520000]: Particle Affector Type 'DeflectorPlane' registered
[ INFO] [1482424511.729550000]: Plugin successfully installed
[ INFO] [1482424511.729632000]: CPU Identifier & Features
[ INFO] [1482424511.729666000]: -------------------------
[ INFO] [1482424511.729694000]:  *   CPU ID: GenuineIntel: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
[ INFO] [1482424511.729723000]:  *      SSE: yes
[ INFO] [1482424511.729743000]:  *     SSE2: yes
[ INFO] [1482424511.729764000]:  *     SSE3: yes
[ INFO] [1482424511.729783000]:  *      MMX: yes
[ INFO] [1482424511.729804000]:  *   MMXEXT: yes
[ INFO] [1482424511.729822000]:  *    3DNOW: no
[ INFO] [1482424511.729843000]:  * 3DNOWEXT: no
[ INFO] [1482424511.729865000]:  *     CMOV: yes
[ INFO] [1482424511.729882000]:  *      TSC: yes
[ INFO] [1482424511.729903000]:  *      FPU: yes
[ INFO] [1482424511.729926000]:  *      PRO: yes
[ INFO] [1482424511.729944000]:  *       HT: no
[ INFO] [1482424511.729962000]: -------------------------
[ INFO] [1482424511.730001000]: ********************************************
***  Starting Mac OS X OpenGL Subsystem  ***
********************************************
[ INFO] [1482424511.730131000]: GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow "OgreWindow(0)", 1x1 windowed  miscParams: FSAA=4 externalGLControl= externalWindowHandle=0 macAPI=carbon
```

Seems like there's something wrong with the OpenGL library provide by the system? Probably related to `ogre` rendering. I installed `ogre` version 1.7.4 via `brew`, both binary install and source compile have been tested, both with no luck.

The system generated a report after `rviz` crashes. I posted the complete report on [Gist here](https://gist.github.com/victl/3c91a9d07b8df7a6f3762b72b52126e8)

And I have tried to `export OGRE_RTT_MODE=FBO` and also 'PBuffer', 'Copy' values, no difference.
Can any one help? Thank you so much.

---

Edit: @William
`osx_ogre_1_9` relies on `qt4`, and I have tried my best to migrate it to `qt5`. However, the compiling process failed at the `sip` command:

```
sip: QMainWindow has not been defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/victor/Repo/ros/ros_kinetic/install_isolated/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py", line 76, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/Cellar/sip/4.18.1/bin/sip', '-c', '/Users/victor/Repo/ros/ros_kinetic/devel_isolated/rviz/bin/sip/rviz_sip', '-b', '/Users/victor/Repo/ros/ros_kinetic/devel_isolated/rviz/bin/sip/rviz_sip/pyqtscripting.sbf', '-I', '/usr/local/share/sip/Qt5', '-w', '-x', 'VendorID', '-t', 'WS_MACX', '-t', 'Qt_5_7_0', '-x', 'Py_v3', 'rviz.sip']' returned non-zero exit status 1
make[2]: *** [/Users/victor/Repo/ros/ros_kinetic/devel_isolated/rviz/bin/sip/rviz_sip/Makefile] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/python_bindings/sip/CMakeFiles/librviz_sip.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I'm not very familiar with `sip`, so I can't tell what to do next

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250623/rviz-crash-on-macos-sierra/) by [ZOU Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28803/zou-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2016-12-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZOU Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28803/zou-lu/) on 2016-12-28**:
Still waiting for helps~~~

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-28**:
It may very well be that you are running into an issue that not many / no one else is running into to. That could explain the lack of response.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-30**:
@ZOU Lu: I've moved your answer to your OP, as it was not really an answer, but an update.

**Comment by [Gorbag](https://answers.ros.org/users/30204/gorbag/) on 2017-04-29**:
It would be great if you posted your tweaks, I'm still struggling to get kinetic installed under Sierra.

**Comment by [ZOU Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28803/zou-lu/) on 2017-04-30**:
@Gorbag I actually fixed almost every issues, including rviz. But I found it's still inconvenient to run ROS on macOS, such as manually compile all packages from src. I recommend you to try install Ubuntu as a virtual machine on your Mac. Using a light weight WM like i3wm, it should run fast.

**Comment by [ZOU Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28803/zou-lu/) on 2017-04-30**:
I don't remember how to tweak them all, some tweaks were ugly, so the best way would be run a virtual machine. Developing under Ubuntu is like a breeze.
I don't like Ubuntu actually, but it do improved my productivity.
By the way, QtCreator is another Swiss Knife you should give a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that rviz erroneously sets macAPI to carbon although it is cocoa - qt5 (5.7.1) is missing the define QT_MAC_USE_COCOA. After editing rviz/src/rviz/ogre_helpers/render_system.cpp, I got rviz to start.

I replaced

```
// Set the macAPI for Ogre based on the Qt implementation
#ifdef QT_MAC_USE_COCOA
  params["macAPI"] = "cocoa";
  params["macAPICocoaUseNSView"] = "true";
#else
  params["macAPI"] = "carbon";
#endif
```

by

```
// Set the macAPI for Ogre based on the Qt implementation
  params["macAPI"] = QT_QPA_DEFAULT_PLATFORM_NAME;
  params["macAPICocoaUseNSView"] = "true";
```

I am using ogre 1.7.4 by the way.

---

Originally posted by [dischu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29049/dischu/) with karma: 56 on 2017-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-14**:
I believe there is logic to detect and set this flag in the CMakeLists, so you can probably update that logic instead of modifying the source code.

**Comment by [dischu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29049/dischu/) on 2017-01-15**:
In case you are using the [ros-install-osx](https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx) install script, you can just add `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DQT_MAC_USE_COCOA"` to the catkin config call. This is brute force, but prevents any modification inside the source tree.